#  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

What is the reason for the following error I am having:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library.

I am using Eclipse 3.5 SE on Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 17):

I had same problem with Oracle Java 7 and Eclipse on 32-bit system.

`libswt-gtk-3.6-java` and `libswt-gtk-3.6-jni` were already installed. [What helped](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/swt-gtk/+bug/975560):

```
cd ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/* .
```

Maybe this can be done reconfiguring Java alternatives or what.

Comment: Solved the problem for me too on Ubuntu 12.04 with 64bit Java (slightly different path).

Comment: I encountered this problem after updating to Precise (12.04), using 32-bit Java 6.  This solution worked for me as well.

Comment: ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, installed java1.7 update 5. same command except "x86" -> "x86_64" worked

Answer (score 3):

I believe [Mikolaj Lechtanski's workaround](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=663734#31) is more elegant.

> create or edit /etc/eclipse.ini
>
> Paste inside:
>
> ```
> -vmargs
> -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni
> ```
>
> exit
>
> make sure the file is readable:
>
> ```
> sudo chmod 755 /etc/eclipse.ini
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This means the native libraries could not be found.
Either you have 32-bit libraries and you are running on a 64-bit machine or vice-versa.
also make sure you have the `-Djava.library.path=` set properly

[See this page on how to run outside of eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/examples.php#standaloneOutsideEclipse)

Answer (score 1):

What versions of Java and Eclipse are you using, and are they 32-bit or 64-bit, and how did you install them?

Eclipse uses its own GUI library called SWT (it doesn't use Java's AWT or Swing), and it needs some native (non-Java) libraries for this. If you have 32-bit Java installed, you need 32-bit Eclipse; if you have 64-bit Java installed, you need 64-bit Eclipse (note, the [Eclipse downloads](http://eclipse.org/downloads/) page has 32-bit and 64-bit versions for Linux).

(Note that it doesn't depend on whether your Linux OS is 32-bit or 64-bit, but on whether your Java is).

Comment: Can i install Java-32-bit on a 64-bit PC (64-bit OS running?).

Comment: @Google Yes, that should work. On Windows it is easy, just run the installer for 32-bit Java; on Linux you might need to install 32-bit compatibility libraries (how exactly depends on your Linux distro).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when running Eclipse remotely on a server via a "ssh -X" tunnel. I resolved it using "sudo apt-get install libswt-gtk-3.6-java" on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when starting some GUI java application on a headless server using X11 forwarding while only having `openjdk-7-jre-headless` installed. Installing the full jre solved the problem:

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing

```
 cd ~/.swt/lib/macosx/x86_64
 ln -s /usr/lib/java/* .
```

which fixed that problem.