# Django on Aptana Studio 3.0

Tags: django, aptana, pydev

When I try to create a new PyDev Django Project I get this error:

```
Error creating Django project.
settings.py file not created
Stdout:
Stderr:
```

Apparently this was meant to have been fixed in 2.5

But I still am experiencing it with the latest Aptana Studio 3.0. The PyDev plugin is version 2.5.02012031515

Any idea please?

Comment: Maybe this is it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10482634/207791

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem.  It is a bug in PyDev that is fixed in 2.5.0.2012040618

According to PyDev there is no way to update the plugins of Aptana Studio. So we are at their mercy to update it soon.

Latest Eclipse is using the latest PyDev mentioned above and it works fine.

**UPDATE:**

I have found the solution here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4759

It is indeed a bug in Aptana 3.1.1, which has been solved now in 3.1.2. I can confirm that this bug has now been solved in latest 3.1.2 stable version on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Kave, I am not sure that's the problem: I can perform the action you can't without problems, and my aptana currently sports PyDev v.2.5.0.2012031515 only, exactly as yours (the link to the bug would help here!).

Comment: oh I see. I thought that could have something to do with it. Its a tough call. All I could put here is the screenshot of the error :(