# Error: no swt-pi-gtk-3139 in java.library.path on win10

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, swt

I am building my first swt app using eclipse. When I run the app I encounter the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-pi-gtk-3139 in java.library.path......

And through searching on google I know one solution is copying the `swt-pi-gtk-3139.dll` to `java.library.path` directory, but I don't know how can I get `swt-pi-gtk-3139.dll` because I can't download it from internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982883/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-could-not-load-swt-l)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library is used by Linux and for eclipse version 3.1. Please use latest version of eclipse 4.6